# C# returning from inside a using block

Tags: c#

will a construct like this, dispose the filehandle correctly?

```
void bla() {
    using (var stream = new new System.IO.StreamReader( filename)) {
        return DoSomethingWithTheStream(stream);
    }
}
```

i.e. will the using trigger the Dispose even though it is returned inside?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is equivalent to:

```
var stream = new StreamReader(fileName);
try {
    return DoSomethingWithTheStream(stream);
}
finally {
    stream.Dispose();
}
```

Since finally clauses are guaranteed to execute, it's guaranteed that the stream is disposed before returning from the method.

Comment: I love examples in reactions. Gives so much more about how it works. +1

Answer (score 4):

Yes. No matter how the block is left, the resource is disposed. This is the value of the `using`-block.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will dispose correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as soon as stream goes out of scope it will be disposed.